# Problem during installation of Rockshox Reverb Stealth product

Tags: seatpost, installation

I am following the SRAM official procedure on a very similar bike to the one reviewed. However, I am stuck at this part: [unthread the hose from the remote's barb](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtVtTd7iQzk&t=1m18s).

I just can't. I am holding the hose very firmly, 10mm away from it's end, and turning the remote counter-clockwise. The hose begins to twist and a 1/8 rotation is achieved only due to hose twisting, no rotation is observed at it's end.

Should I use pliers? Put something soft underneath? The product is brand-new, boxed.

[image]

After trying to unscrew the hose 3, I decided I need to unscrew 2. I used a wrench and it took me some time to realize this is different than in the video. One drop of oil spilled. I tightened it not very much, although probably more than original.

I tried with 1 turned all the way to either direction, but the hose doesn't come off.

Comment: They're definitely separating 2 from 3 but achieving it from turning 1 and 2 together. I'd carefully try to hold 3 in vice grips and use a pair of pliers to turn 2 to unthread it. Where are you Vorac? Do you have an LBS that's happy to provide free advice?

Comment: I wouldn't clamp the hose at all, they're not keen on that. If it's going to unscrew, it should do so by hand. Don't force anything or you'll regret it. Are you sure you have a threaded hose barb?

Comment: @alex, yes, from the manual: "Hold the hose barb by hand, then turn the remote assembly counter-clockwise to unthread the hose barb from the hose."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alex was right in advising not to use tools where no tools are needed. Similarly, it is easy to run frame BBs or brankarm threads by forcing the thread with a wrench, instead of by hand.

Somehow, I had made the hose hard to unscrew by overtightening 2. I loosened it up, held it with a wrench and rotated the hose by hand. This solved the problem.